# Unique aggregate function when singular value is guaranteed by the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, sql-limit

Given the following:

```
CREATE TABLE A (A1 INTEGER, A2 INTEGER, A3 INTEGER);

INSERT INTO A(A1, A2, A3) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO A(A1, A2, A3) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
```

I want to select the maximum `A1` given specific `A2` and `A3` values, and have those values (`A2` and `A3`) also appear in the returned row (e.g. so that I may use them in a join since the SELECT below is meant for a sub-query).

It would seem logical to be able to do the following, given that A2 and A3 are hardcoded in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(A1) AS A1, A2, A3 FROM A WHERE A2=1 AND A3=1
```

However, PostgreSQL (and I suspect other RDBMs as well) balks at that and requests an aggregate function for A2 and A3 even though their value is fixed. So instead, I either have to do a:

```
SELECT MAX(A1) AS A1, MAX(A2), MAX(A3) FROM A WHERE A2=1 AND A3=1
```

or a:

```
SELECT MAX(A1) AS A1, 1, 1 FROM A WHERE A2=1 AND A3=1
```

The first alternative I don't like cause I could have used `MIN` instead and it would still work, whereas the second alternative doubles the number of positional parameters to provide values for when used from a programming language interface. Ideally I would have wanted a `UNIQUE` aggregate function which would assert that all values are equal and return that single value, or even a `RANDOM` aggregate function which would return one value at random (since I know from the `WHERE` clause that they are all equal).

Is there an idiomatic way to write the above in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler, you only need `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3      -- add more columns as you please
FROM   a
WHERE  a2 = 1 AND a3 = 1
ORDER  BY 1 DESC      -- 1 is just a positional reference (syntax shorthand)
LIMIT  1;
```

`LIMIT 1` is Postgres specific syntax.
The [SQL standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause) would be:

```
...
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

My first answer with [`DISTINCT ON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause) was for the more complex case where you'd want to retrieve the maximum `a1` per various combinations of `(a2,a3)`

Aside: I am using [lower case identifiers for a reason](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Should't that be "ORDER BY a1 DESC LIMIT 1" as I want the max(a1) for the given a2 and a3 values?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: You are right. I misread your question first and was thinking of a more complex case. Amended, with some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```
select max(A1),A2,A3 from A GROUP BY A2,A3;
```

**EDIT**

```
select A1,A2,A3 from A where A1=(select max(A1) from A ) limit 1
```

Comment: it does work though I would prefer not to use Group By as it is non-intuitive for this particular use case. I suspect it boils down to aggregate functions not being able to assert or throw an exception, otherwise a UNIQUE() aggregate would have been possible; still a RANDOM aggregate function might also be envisioned for this case as it doesn't have to throw an exception under any circumstances.

Comment: Well you could limit the number of rows returned. Try the query in the edited section

Answer (score 1):

how about group by

```
select 
a2
,a3
,MAX(a1) as maximumVal
from a
group by a2, a3
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard trick to obtain the *maximal row* without an aggregate function is to guantee the absense of a larger value by means of a NOT EXISTS subquery. (This does not work when there are ties, but neither would the subquery with the max) When needed, it would not be too difficult to add a tie-breaker condition.

Another solution would be a subquery with a window function `row_number()` or `rank()`

```
SELECT *
FROM a src
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM a nx
    WHERE nx.a2 = src.a2
    AND nx.a3 = src.a3
    AND nx.a1 > src.a1
    );
```